# Missing Method Exceptions in VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, missingmethodexception, missingmethod

I keep getting missing method exceptions when using VS2019.

I have a solution called DailyAnalytics. This references DLLs for Analytics_Product1, Analytics_Product2, etc. These in turn reference a DLL called Utilities (all of these DLLs are on my machine). The methods which show as missing when running DailyAnalytics are indeed in Utilities - in fact, I can run Analytics_Product1 (etc) from another solution with no errors, but when calling from DailyAnalytics, the missing method exceptions are thrown.

I have tried: 1) cleaning and rebuilding Utilities; 2) cleaning and rebuilding Analytics_Product1 (etc); 3) removing references in Analytics_Product1 (etc) to Utilities and re-adding them; and 4) removing references in DailyAnalytics to Analytics_Product1 (etc) and re-adding them.

None of the above has worked.

Actual error messages are of the form "System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Utilities.AnalyticsFunctions.SomeMethod()' at AnalysisProduct1()"

Comment: Silly question, but do you have to correct version of these libraries/DLLs?

Comment: Are the dlls installed in the GAC? If not, are they copy local?

Comment: 1. After restarting the PC, I no long get missing method exceptions for the Utilities methods - but instead get the same error for two calls to a different method (in a Statistics library)! And I can still run Analytics_Product1 (etc) from another solution with no issues. 2. I used gacutil.exe and typed gacutil -l [nameOfLibrary].txt which returned Number of items [in GAC] = 0